# Use subqueries to assign column values for each record in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

As i know, "Subqueries can assign column values for each record".

example: lets consider this database,

[Example database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsH6N.png)

```
user (id, name, age)
user_detail (user_id[foreign], user_email, address)
```

Now we can select all email and name by subquery like this:

```
    SELECT id, (SELECT user_email FROM user_detail WHERE user_detail.user_id = user.id LIMIT 1) as email,
    name, age 
       FROM user
          WHERE 1
```

This will the output table like:

```
 _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
| id | email | name | age |
+-------------------------+
---------All rows----------
```

Now how can i query with it laravel eloquent?

More specific ...
I have some tables,

```
1. session (id, name)
2. account (id, name, group)
3. action (id, action_name, detail)
4. another_table (id, detail)
5. transaction (id, from_account_id, to_account_id, session_id,
   action_table_id, another_table_id, other_attributes )
```

now i want a single query to get each line as a object, and hole a array
query should return

```
result (transaction_id, session_name, from_account_name, to_account_name,
        action_name, another_table_detail, other_attributes)
```

and finally send them to json, such that i read them by just a for loop.

Comment: Why do you have to use a subquery? Are you familiar with [Eloquent relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent-relationships)?

Comment: Thanks for you reply #Jonas. I wanna learn subquery with laravel and apply them with 4 to 5 table joining. If i use relation than it goes so expensive with eloquent (as i know). That is the tow reason. Can you help me to reach out?

Comment: well, more specific ...
lets have some tables, 
1. session (id, name)
2. account (id, name, group)
3. action (id, action_name, detail)
4. another_table (id, detail)
5. transaction (id, from_account_id, to_account_id, session_id, action_table_id, another_table_id, other_attributes )

now i want a single query to get each line as a object, and hole a array
query should return 

result (transaction_id, session_name, from_account_name, to_account_name, action_name, another_table_detail, other_attributes)

and finally send them to json, such that i read them by just a for loop.

Comment: You can create a subquery with [`selectSub()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/1d349728e0b89498e93a2c3cbb3ddde0b74ba92e/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php#L236).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am looking for this. and it works with selectSub().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks [Jonas-staudenmeir.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4848587/jonas-staudenmeir) He helps me to find the solution.

In that case we can use `selectSub()` method from laravel query builder class. [selectSub()](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/1d349728e0b89498e93a2c3cbb3ddde0b74ba92e/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php#L236)

For first one:

```
    $user_email = DB::table('user_detail')
                ->select('user_detail.user_email')
                ->whereRaw('user_detail.user_id = user.id')
                ->take(1);

    $data = DB::table('user')
            ->select('name', 'age')
            ->selectSub($user_email, 'email') // selectSub(sub_query, as) 
            ->get();
```

For second one:

```
    //session query
    $session = DB::table('session')
                ->select('session.name')
                ->whereRaw('transaction.session_id = session.id')
                ->take(1);
    //from_account query
    $from_account = DB::table('account')
                ->select('account.name')
                ->whereRaw('transaction.from_account_id = account.id')
                ->take(1);
    //to_account query
    $to_account = DB::table('account')
                ->select('account.name')
                ->whereRaw('transaction.to_account_id = account.id')
                ->take(1);
    //action query
    $action = DB::table('action')
                ->select('action.action_name')
                ->whereRaw('transaction.action_table_id = action.id')
                ->take(1);
    //another_table query
    $another_table = DB::table('another_table')
                ->select('another_table.detail')
                ->whereRaw('transaction.another_table_id = another_table.id')
                ->take(1);

    $data = DB::table('transaction')
            ->select('transaction.id as transaction_id', 'other_attributes')
            ->selectSub($session, 'session_name') //session as session_name
            ->selectSub($from_account, 'from_account_name') //from_account as from_account_name
            ->selectSub($to_account, 'session_name') //to_account as to_account_name
            ->selectSub($action, 'action_name') //action as action_name
            ->selectSub($another_table, 'another_table_detail') //another_table as another_table_detail
            ->get();
```

Though we can use join or left join. Which one is faster it all depends on the data, indexes, correlation, amount of data, query, etc. Subqueries can be slower than LEFT [OUTER] JOINS, but in my opinion their strength is slightly higher readability. [join-vs-sub-query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577174/join-vs-sub-query)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$users = User::join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'user_detail')->get();
```

Should join two tables with all the records you need.

Comment: Thanks for you reply #rkg. I have this idea and that is a quite good solution. But i want to use it from subqueries. and i am stuck on it. can you help me to reach out?